# Analysis. Supremum and infimum.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A,B \subset\mathbb{R}$ and $C =\{x+y | x ∈ A,y ∈ B\}$. How are the numbers $\inf A$, $\inf B$, and $\inf C$ related? How are the numbers $\sup A$, $\sup B$, and $\sup C$ related?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. You will find your experience much improved if instead of simply quoting the problem you are struggling with (or have been assigned to do), you provide both *context* (where did the problem come from? What is your level?) and also explain what you have done to try to solve it and where you are running into difficulties. That way, the answers can be given at the appropriate level and not cover material you already know (or fail to solve your difficulties). Otherwise, you may find the question getting closed for lack of effort on your part.

Comment: Do you have any guesses? Maybe try some examples first, and see if you can come up with a conjecture to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the properties of the infimum,

$$ \inf(C) = \inf(A) + \inf (B) $$

To prove, you can use the theorem that if a number $z$ is a lower bound of $X$ and there is a sequence of numbers of the set $X$ approaching $z$, then $z$ is the infimum of $X$.

Same applies for the supremum.

Comment: Nice answer! Welcome to MSE $\ddot\smile$